# Select the element with class as a filter

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie when it comes to jQuery and having a little problem with `.parents()`. The thing is when I use `.parents('span[class^="lid"]')`, my codes works and am getting what I want, which is to get the *element* with `class` as a filter. But when I use `.parents('span[class~="header"]')` or `.parents('span[class^="header"]')`, am not getting the `<span>` *element* to be displayed.

Below is my code: [Click here to view](http://jsbin.com/azurat/2/edit)

I know for a certain that `~=` selector checks if it is exactly equal to any of the words and `^=` checks if the value beginning is matched.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an "attributes selector", not a "class selector", so it gets the value of the attribute, and that value is :

```
"lid_1 header1"
```

It does **not** check for each class, it just compares the string in the attribute and sees it if starts with the given string etc. This is why :

```
span[class*="header"]
```

will work, as the string contains "header", but it does not start with "header", so :

```
span[class^="header"]
```

will not work.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's selection works like CSS, so you can select a class by using a dot (.)

```
$('tag.class');
$('tag#id');
...
```

So, in your case:

```
.parents('span.header');
```

Comment: thanks @Tim for answering, but am looking for a way to use the `span[class^="lid"]` _and the like_ pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly by using this code

```
var parentEls = $("b").parents('span.lid_1').map(function() {
  return this.tagName;
}).get().join(", ");
$("b").append("<strong>" + parentEls + "</strong>");
```

Test the code on http://jsbin.com/azurat/7/edit

Comment: thanks @Rohan for answering, but am looking for a way to use the `span[class^="lid"]` _and the like_ pattern.

Comment: This link will give you what you want http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

For Example:

`[class*=lid] will select elements whose classname contains 'lid'
[class~=lid] will select elements whose classname has the word 'lid' (delimited with spaces)
[class$=lid] will select elements whose classname ends in 'lid'`